# ARIMA first order differencing shows strange pattern

Tags: r, time-series, arima, stationarity, differencing

I have came across with a strange issue when I employ a first order differencing to make the original time series stationary. 
The original ts is with 1-min recording interval and over 2months.
Since the ACF plot attenuates very slowly for the original ts and ADF test shows the ts is not stationary.
[image: original ts plot]
[image: ACF plot of original time series]

The differenced ts plot shows very strange pattern,
[image: differenced ts plot]
 probably because the there are many consecutive duplicated observations in the original time series,for example
[image: duplicated data example]

My questions are
(1)Does this kind of pattern looks stationary? Since I haven't seen any ts plot like this, I have no idea.

(2)Are there any better way to handle consecutive duplicated observations. I tried to calculate the 5-min 
mean of the original ts and then set up model on it but the model will be totally different.

(3) Is that okay to use this kind of differenced time series for further model identification，or should I use the auto.arima() to set up model on original undifferenced time series？
The second method is definitely easier.But which will give a better estimation?

I will be very grateful if someone can give me a answer as soon as possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: as far as I know, it's not possible to model a time  series with such behavior. can't you just consider a larger time unit so that, if the series repeats, you just consider that as one value. If you can't, I don't see your series as being amenable to time-series methods.  but maybe someone else is familiar with an approach ?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I decide to use the data at every five minutes to do differencing, the result looks better and proves to be stationary by KPSS test. But I am still waiting for maybe there is a better way to handle this kind of data.

Comment: do you know the reason for the repetition ? I'm not positive that my suggestion is legal because you're actually changing the series.  ( and  you're still going to have repetition but it will be less ). Hopefully someone else can chime in here because I have no experience with this situation.  I would say "google" for X but I'm not even sure what X should be. I might look around on the internet if I have time.

Comment: The reason could be the measuring frequency is too high, the system change slower than the measuring process. Or simply because of rounding of the original measured data. I am also not sure about this way to deal with the problem. But I found a interesting paper about the impact of time aggregation on the ARIMA modeling yesterday.(link:https://www.census.gov/ts/papers/Conference1978/Wei1978.pdf)

Comment: Hi: That paper is more relevant for saying having weekly data and needing to build a model for monthly etc. I'm not so sure that type of case is relevant to what you're doing but, if you think so, go for it. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help but, if you type in "temporal aggregation" in google there are quite a few papers on temporal aggregation of time series that are similar ( in concept ) to that of Wei's.